# List dates between two dates for only particular days dynamically

Tags: java, date, datetime, time

I have a `presentation` table which consist of these values:

```
ID     DAY         START       END      STARTDATE       ENDDATE
622   Monday     12:00:00    02:00:00   01-05-2016     04-06-2016 
623   Tuesday    12:00:00    02:00:00   01-05-2016     04-06-2016 
624   Wednesday  08:00:00    10:00:00   01-05-2016     04-06-2016 
625   Thursday   10:00:00    12:00:00   01-05-2016     04-06-2016
```

So basically, my `STARTDATE` is 01-05-2016 until `ENDDATE` 04-06-2016

I figured how to list dates between these two dates like this :

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.setTime(presentationDateStart);
                while (cal.getTime().before(presentationDateEnd)) {
                    cal.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
                    System.out.println("poop "+cal.getTime());

                }
```

However, this will list ALL of the possible dates in this format : `Sun May 08 00:00:00 SGT 2016`

How can I get only particular dates based on `DAY` in my `presentation` table dynamically?
The values of `presentation` table are always dynamic.

UPDATE:

I only want list of dates which ONLY consists of DAY in my `presentation` table. Format does not matters to me (yet).

Expected outcome:

```
Mon May 02 00:00:00 SGT 2016
Tue May 03 00:00:00 SGT 2016
Wed May 04 00:00:00 SGT 2016
Thu May 05 00:00:00 SGT 2016
Mon May 09 00:00:00 SGT 2016
Tue May 10 00:00:00 SGT 2016
Wed May 11 00:00:00 SGT 2016
Thu May 12 00:00:00 SGT 2016 so on until end of the date
```

**UPDATE**

This is my JAVA code :

```
            String presentationID = null;
            String presentationDay = null;
            Date presentationStart = null;
            Date presentationEnd = null;
            Date presentationDateStart = null;
            Date presentationDateEnd = null;
            String presentationFreeID = null;

            List list1 = new ArrayList() ;
            list1 = GenerateScheduleDAO.getPresentation();
            PresentationBean[] presentation = new PresentationBean[list1.size()];
            for(int c = 0 ; c < list1.size() ; c++){

                presentation[c] = (PresentationBean) list1.get(c);

                presentationID = presentation[c].getPresentationID();
                presentationDay = presentation[c].getPresentationDay();
                presentationStart = presentation[c].getPresentationStart();
                presentationEnd = presentation[c].getPresentationEnd();
                presentationDateStart = presentation[c].getPresentationDateStart();
                presentationDateEnd = presentation[c].getPresentationDateEnd();
                presentationFreeID = presentation[c].getFreeID();

                System.out.println(" pFID11: "+ presentationFreeID +" pID: "+ presentationID +" pDay: "+ presentationDay+ " PStart: "+ presentationStart+" pEnd: "+ presentationEnd+" DStart: "+presentationDateStart+" EDate: "+ presentationDateEnd);

                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.setTime(presentationDateStart);
                while (cal.getTime().before(presentationDateEnd)) {
                    cal.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
                    System.out.println("poop "+cal.getTime());

                }

            }
```

In db, `DAY` is stored in `VARCHAR2`.

Comment: This is not quite clear enough to be answered.  Please provide some examples of what you mean, with enough context that an unambiguous set of rules can be described.

Comment: The question is not clear. Btw you can always add a check for the day in the output format.

Comment: Do you mean by using DAY_OF_WEEK? @direwolf7

Comment: Declare a result list in top of the function. Generate the dates in the same way, and then add to the result list only if the day in the format is the one you want. And after all the dates, return that list from the function.

Comment: Updated my question @JimGarrison

Comment: can you show an example? @direwolf7

Comment: I think I understand that you want to repeat each day (Monday from Start to finish, by Monday; Tuesday, from its start to its finish by Tuesday, etc.)   IN which case you execute your loop 4 times and add 7 days instead of 1 to the first day.   Alternately you iterate by day and put on a check `int dayOfWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);` and compare whether that's a valid day of the week; `continue;` if it's not.

Comment: I am sorry when you said about loop 4 times, does that because i have four possible days in my `presentation` table? @DanielWiddis

Comment: @DanielWiddis I would appreciate if you can provide me with an example

Comment: @user6308605 How can I access the day of week in your table?  What format is it stored in?

Comment: @user6308605 it sounds like your presentation table is in a database.  You are asking a question in java.  So please provide whatever code/format you are using to get the information from the database into java so we can help you further.  We can't guess.

Comment: Updated my question :) @DanielWiddis

Answer (score 2):

you can use `Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK` to get the day index, and print (include) only the days you need

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(presentationDateStart);
while (cal.getTime().before(presentationDateEnd)) {
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
    if(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == 2 || cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == 3 || cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == 4 || cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == 5){
        //2, 3 ,4 ,5 are the index of days mon-Thu
        //constants available too : Calendar.MONDAY ... 
        System.out.println("poop "+cal.getTime());
    }
}//date is before endDate
```

if you have a dynamic source for day-index you can get this list an compare `DAY_OF_WEEK` value against it (array or arraylist) ?

for more info regarding `DAY_OF_WEEK` [check docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#SUNDAY)

**EDIT:**
i have already mentioned that you can use a dynamic day-index array
here is a sample of what i mean:

```
ArrayList<Integer> dayIndex = getDayIndex();// could be from DB, API... it contains day index (1,4,6) the days you want to include
if(dayIndex .contains(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)){
    System.out.println("poop "+cal.getTime());
}
```

Comment: Thank you @yazan. I understand your codes perfectly. But I think this is hard coded. As i mention before, `presentation` table is dynamic. The days may change. It does not necessarily Monday, tuesday, wednesday and thursday. The values i gave were just as an example...

Comment: @user6308605 my answer already have that. you can provide an array of day index (dynamically) to filter days based on theat

Comment: @user6308605 this is the correct answer depending on how you are getting the presentation table into Java.  You need to tell us how we can access that information.

Comment: I am sorry @Yazan I dont understand about `getDayIndex()`. I tried it and it has error.. How can i correct this?

Comment: it's a method (not in Java API) i just gave any random name, anyways, this method supposed to return the `presentation table` or the list of days you want to print.